# mouseover image popup image at another location

Tags: javascript, html, popup, mouseover, onmouseover

I have a column of buttons that have to do the same thing as the first button but with there own individual pics. How do I set the id so that there's no glitches? Here is what I have so far http://ultimatefinishdetailing.com/Services.html

HTML: (posted HTML BEFORE on the image button)

```
<STYLE MEDIA="screen" TYPE="text/css">
.pop-up {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: -100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position:absolute;
right:-50px;
top:75px;
}
.button {
      width:300px;
      height:21px;
      display:block; background-image:url(images/button_ufad4.jpg);
      position:absolute;
}
</style>
<a href="" class="button" onmouseover="javascript:ShowImage('images/InteriorandExteriorDetailing.jpg')" onmouseout="javascript:HideImage()"></a>

<div id="popup" class="pop-up">
   <img id="popupImage" alt="Popup image" /> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowImage(src)
    {
        var img = document.getElementById('popupImage');
        var div = document.getElementById('popup');
        img.src = src;
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
    function HideImage()
    {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nishant is correct for the mouseout, you are just missing the first single quote.

For the style you would probably want something like this

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
.pop-up {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position:absolute;
right:50px;
top:50px;
}
</style>
```

The position: absolute; will tell the browser to put it exactly where you want it. In this example I told it to position itself 50px from the top and 50px from the right. You can also use the keywords "bottom" and "left".

Comment: awesome. I will put this in!!

Comment: I did it and the style works! now what should I put in the first quote...i actually have no idea

Answer (score 1):

Here try this...

CSS

```
<style>
  .pop-up {
     height: 200px;
     width: 100px;
     margin-right: 100px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     float: right;
 display:none;
  }

 .button {
      /*change the width and height to match button.jpg's*/
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
      display:block;
  background-image:url(image/button.jpg);
  }
</style>
```

HTML

```
<a href="" class="button" onmouseover="javascript:ShowImage('images/eco.jpg')" onmouseout="javascript:HideImage()"></a>

<div id="popup" class="pop-up">
   <img id="popupImage" alt="Popup image" /> 
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowImage(src)
    {
        var img = document.getElementById('popupImage');
        var div = document.getElementById('popup');
        img.src = src;
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
    function HideImage()
    {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I added that button code under my popup css code and it didn't do anything...where should I add the button code so that the mousover is the button not the text?

Comment: im trying to add the css button code your talking about...not working

Comment: You need to add it to the a tag

Comment: i added it to the syle tag and it didn't do anything except make everything not work....could you show me an example please? this is the last thing i need to figure out! im so close

Comment: added it to the a tag like you said. and it got rid of the mousover on all the other buttons...but it won't mouseover that entire button and changing the parameters doesn't do anything except show text...should i wrap it in style tags?

Comment: put the `.button` class in the style tag you already have. then add `class="button"` to the `a` tag

Comment: I don't know what's up with your coding but it doesnt seem to work. I put the class button exactly where you have it and it pops up with some red image that I can alter to wrap around the button image on my site but still then I can't get the popup to show unless i hover mouse over the very bottom of the button image....maybe there's a way to get that .button to go absolute and make it transparent so I can see my image button. idk. I'm going to redo everything in your code one more time

Comment: I messed around with it some more. Your code DOES work; however, I do not want that button that is in your code being the button that shows...i need the image that i had in its place to be the only thing that shows. I hope we are on the same page now. So how do I make that image....the button?

Comment: Then just remove the `background-color` and `border` from the class and remove the word 'push' from inside the `a` tag. if you use `background-image` and change the `width` and `height`, you change that button into whatever you want.

Comment: Do I add this before, inside, or after in the image HTML? I added it before and the mousover is at the very top of the image....I add it after and the mousover is at the very bottom...I add it in the middle and the image disappears not matter where I move the mouse

Comment: Here is what I put in my style:    <style>
  .pop-up {
     height: 200px;
     width: 100px;
     margin-right: 100px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     float: right;
 display:none;
  }

 .button {
      width:300px;
      height:20px;
      display:block;
}
 .background-image {
      width:300px;
      height:50px;
}

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to use `background-image`. You should really think about looking up this info at w3schools or something because this is really basic.

Comment: you...did it...you actually freakin did it!!! Thank you so much!! it took forever but i see exactly how you did it and I'm so happy now...been working on this for .....100+ straight hours...so sad. Im gonna check that w3schools out because I can't believe this is "basic"...i really don't know much then. dude...you awesome!

Comment: No prob... just remember to accept this as the best answer I could use the rep. lol And if you need anymore help don't be a afraid to ask

Comment: I will! I do have three more questions but I don't want to confuse you so I will ask one at a time. First off, could you look at the code up top(that's what I'm using) and tell me if anything at all is "off" about it that could possibly glitch things? I'm getting a transparent box figure showing up to the right of my button and even though everything works...don't quite know what that is

Comment: and by look at the code up top I mean look at my original post (i updated it) thx! I tried messing around with the style but the ghost box is still there until you mousover...i wonder if it's part of the popup code that's not right

Answer (score 0):

To fix the position where the popupimage occurs, you'll need to write a style for #popupImage and place it wherever you want it to appear.

For the 'onmouseout' not working issue... firstly, your HTML has a missing single quote and a closing the open anchor tag... It should be...

```
<a href="" onmouseover="ShowImage('images/eco.jpg')" onmouseout="HideImage('images/button_ufad4.jpg')"></a>
```

Notice the missing first single quote.

Secondly, in your function, you are not making use of the image "images/button_ufad4.jpg" in any way, so simply adding the additional quote in the begining of the image name should fix the onmouseout problem

Comment: i don't know how to write a "style" but I am taking your word on the Html quote missing. I see what your saying there. Ima fix that right now!

Comment: You may refer to @Developer Gee reply for the styling. You need to simply copy the style "code" he has provided and paste/overwrite it on your own code of the .pop-up

Comment: I added the single quote and now my popup goes away! thx...now on to the other problems

Comment: thank you for your help. you were right. now i just gotta figure out my last problem. i can't seem to get the mouseover to be on that top button...it's on all the buttons

Comment: That's because you haven't copy pasted the code properly... please copy and paste it again (in your code, the opening anchor tag is not closing properly, and the closing anchor tag is not present at all)

Comment: ok...im a little confused because i don't see it yet, but i will look very closely...you know what your talking about

Comment: ok! i put the anchor tags in ...however now there is no mouseover whatsoever. ....so im going to do some css with the button?....i guess that might fix it????

Comment: I added this:.button {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:block;
} just like josh said below to...added it into my <a tags and it got rid of the mouseover on all the buttons...now how do i get it to mouseover on just that one entire button. it only mousover the very bottom of that button

Comment: i updated my website with the changes...that should give you a good idea of what im missing now. just one more thing

Comment: @JasonSutphin, You need to put the </a> just before <!--$end htmlAfter$-->

Comment: put the </a> where? whats <!--$end htmlAfter$--> ?

Comment: if you check my website out now, you can see how the image is not the actual "button" and the mousover only works at the bottom of it. how do I make that image the button? I don't want to use a link because it doesn't look good at all. I want to use the image

Comment: Ok, then do the following changes... Remove `<A HREF="" ONMOUSEOVER="ShowImage('images/InteriorandExteriorDetailing.jpg')" ONMOUSEOUT="HideImage('images/button_ufad4.jpg')">`, then remove the `</A>` soon after the `.button` style, then remove `</STYLE>` just before the `<A` that you have just deleted, and place it after the end of the style `.button`, and finally, add the `ONMOUSEOVER` and `ONMOUSEOUT` events to the parent `div`

Comment: I will do that....i will try my best since I'm not an expert like you for sure. thank you so much for helping me by the way; you are really brilliant

Comment: Im going to update my first post to reflect just exactly what code I have in it right now....cause I'm looking at your post and ...not clicking to me. I think because i changed something and it's not what's on my site right now....dang.

Comment: ok, updated first post. Now I know my .button is messed up.....that may be my problem, but I don't know what to but in its place...this isn't adding up to me

Comment: ok. i'm sure i changed something before you posted that last thing. I did exactly what you said and now nothing works. unless I don't know what ONMOUSEOVER and ONMOUSEOUT event to parent div mean.....cause I added <A HREF="" ONMOUSEOVER=" all the way to .jpg')"> inside the div tag....must be wrong

Comment: nevermind!! I got it!! it's fixed...i will post my end code up for all to see when I update the site completely...here very shortly. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: hey I updated the first post...i am having two new problems after the major fix. I have a ghost box that is on my page that won't go away until you mousover....and I don't know how to set the id's so that the other buttons will work without glitching eachother. Mind helping me one last time?

Comment: @JasonSutphin, when you have a new question, its always better to create a new question, so anybody else facing the same issue as you can refer to these answers. Now if you change the question itself, nobody will be able to refer to the solutions, as it'l only confuse them further.

Comment: your right, good idea. thx. I want to give you rep points but I would be taking it away from the other guy who helped me as well. Take care